# About smoothness of  pasted function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $M\subset \mathbb R^2$   be a halfplane and $X$ be a Banach space.

We say that a function $f:M\rightarrow X$ is a  of class $C^\infty$ on $M$ if it is of class $C^\infty$ on $int M$, for each multiindex $\alpha$   and for each $x$ from boundary of $M$  there exists  $\lim_{y\rightarrow x \atop y\in int M} D^\alpha f(y)$, and function $D^\alpha f$ defined on $int M$ in usual sense and for $x$ from boundary by $D^\alpha f(x) =\lim_{y\rightarrow x \atop y\in int M} D^\alpha f(y)$ is continuous.

Let $M_1=(-\infty, 0] \times \mathbb R$, $M_2=[0,\infty) \times \mathbb R$.

Let's assume that  functions $f:M_1\rightarrow X$, $g: M_2 \rightarrow X$ are of class $C^\infty$.

Is it the function $h:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow X $ defined by $h(x,y)=f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in M_1$ and $h(x,y)=g(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\in M_2$  of clas C^\infty$?

Edit:

I forgot to add that for each $(x,y)$ from the boundary of M  we assume $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ and for each boundary point $(x,y)$ and each multindex $\alpha$ we assume that $D^\alpha f(x,y)=D^\alpha g(x,y)$.

Comment: What about taking $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $h(x,y)=(|x|,y)$?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to write that in each  boundary point $(x,y)$  $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ and    for each $\alpha$ and $(x,y)$ from boundary  $D^\alpha f(x,y)=D^\alpha g(x,y)$.

Comment: With your edit, I think the function $h$ is smooth by definition - you are forcing all derivatives of all orders to be continuous.